# This seller doesn’t accept payments in your currency

Tags: paypal

I have a website with a PayPal merchant account in India.

If a user from my website tries to make a 1 USD payment through their PayPal account, it shows the error message "We’re sorry. This seller doesn’t accept payments in your currency. Please return to the seller and choose another way to pay."

If they pay via the Debit or Credit Card option, it says Things don't appear to be working right now.

However, I have both USD and INR currency support in my merchant account.

Can anyone tell me a solution to pay with USD currency from within India? how can we handle this? can we handle both international and local payments in PayPal? is there any automatic currency detection available based on country?

do any other payment gateway easier to handle both local and international currencies?

Answer (score 1):

For payments within India, local regulations require the currency to be INR. However, support for INR and domestic transactions in India was announced to be going away soon (April 1)

Going forward, it seems PayPal in India should only be used for *international* payments -- either the buyer or the seller should have an account that is not Indian, and the currency can be USD or any other PayPal supported currency.